# Selecting rows within group based on field that can have a value or is null

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by, sql-server-2008-r2

From the table below for each IssID FieldID group, I'd like to select the row that Contains the lowest ChgGrpID value, if there is a row in the group that this field IS NULL, then still select the lowest non null value. If only a row with NULL exists then select that row for the group.

```
create table #Projects
(ProjectID int, IssID int, PtID int, PTY varchar(10), TypeID int, TypeName varchar(20), FieldID int, FieldName varchar(20),         STRINGVALUE varchar(50), NUMBERVALUE int,ChgGrpID int,ChgGrpIssID int,ChgItemID int,ChgItemGrpID int,FIELD varchar(20),            NEWVALUE varchar(20), NEWSTRING varchar(20))
insert into #Projects values 
(10879,107930,3,'Super',22,'A',10648,'ADH',NULL,666,501040,107930,852895,501040,'ADH',NULL,'666')
,(10879,107930,3,'Super',22,'A',10571,'DLV','No',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107930,3,'Super',22,'A',10541,'CMPLX','Large',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107930,3,'Super',22,'A',10542,'EWF','Orange',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107930,3,'Super',22,'A',10654,'WKFL','UAT',NULL,501034,107930,852889,501034,'WKFL','DVP','CRV')
,(10879,107930,3,'Super',22,'A',10654,'WKFL','UAT',NULL,501037,107930,852892,501037,'WKFL','CRV','UAT')
,(10879,107930,3,'Super',22,'A',10654,'WKFL','UAT',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107971,3,'Super',103,'B',10648,'ADH',NULL,999,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107971,3,'Super',103,'B',10571,'DLV','No',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107971,3,'Super',103,'B',10541,'CMPLX','Large',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107971,3,'Super',103,'B',10542,'EWF','Orange',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107971,3,'Super',103,'B',10654,'WKFL','UAT',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)


select * from #Projects 
order by IssID, FieldID
```

Here's the result I'd like to see:

```
insert into #Projects values 
(10879,107930,3,'Super',22,'A',10648,'ADH',NULL,666,501040,107930,852895,501040,'ADH',NULL,'666')
,(10879,107930,3,'Super',22,'A',10571,'DLV','No',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107930,3,'Super',22,'A',10541,'CMPLX','Large',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107930,3,'Super',22,'A',10542,'EWF','Orange',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107930,3,'Super',22,'A',10654,'WKFL','UAT',NULL,501034,107930,852889,501034,'WKFL','DVP','CRV')
,(10879,107971,3,'Super',103,'B',10648,'ADH',NULL,999,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107971,3,'Super',103,'B',10571,'DLV','No',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107971,3,'Super',103,'B',10541,'CMPLX','Large',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107971,3,'Super',103,'B',10542,'EWF','Orange',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(10879,107971,3,'Super',103,'B',10654,'WKFL','UAT',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL)
```

Comment: I hate questions like these.  No offense but these are here is what I have do my homework for me.  Can you try to break it up a bit and attempt it and post back what help you really need?

Comment: It's not homework and I'm just asking for a some advice. Essentially I need to select rows within a group where a field can have a value or NULL, when there are more than one rows and one has NULL in the field, select the row with the smallest NON-NULL value. If only one row with NULL in the field then select that row.

Comment: Here's the answer: `select * from 
(
 select *, row_number() over (partition by IssID, CustomFieldID order by Isnull(ChgGrpID, 2147483647)) as rn 
 from #Project
 
) p
where rn = 1`

Answer (score 0):

The first trick is that nulls are the last values picked by min - they are larger than any number for min(), and smaller than any number for max(). This means your desired behavior is the default.

The second trick is that you cannot join nulls, so you need to use isnull(). (If it is possible to have an ID of -1, you must pick a different replacement value.)

So we find our minimum values, and the other items in the key, then use this as a subquery to pick the rows we want:

```
Select p.* from #Projects p
join
(Select isnull(MIN(ChgGrpID),-1) as ChgGrpID, IssID, FieldID
from #Projects 
group by IssID, FieldID) X
on isnull(P.ChgGrpID,-1)=X.ChgGrpID and P.IssID=X.IssID and P.FieldID=X.FieldID
```